# Joomla 3.0.4 - not able to login to administrator

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I downloaded the files and database from the production server to my local machine and have been able to connect them, which displays a working website.

I tried logging into the admin but wasn't able to do so. The site gets redirected to domain.com/index.php

I later found out the error:
`echo $this->baseurl;`

This statement should return domain.com/administrator but only returns domain.com.. This causes the form to post the login value as only index.php instead of administrator/index.php..

For the interim, I did a browser hack to access the admin panel. How do I fix this globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some analysis found out that in configuration.php there is a variable called as $live_site which needs to be set to blank (public $live_site = ''; ). If set to something else  then the above problem occurs.

Comment: have to wait for another 18 hours as of now to accept my own answer. Thanks for that anyways :) !!